# Conexão com banco de dados MySql em Python

Tags: mysql, sql, python, python-3.x, conexão

Tentando realizar a conexão com meu banco de dados, mas está me retornando o seguinte erro!

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'Connection' object has no
>   attribute 'execute' Exception has occurred: AttributeError
>   'Connection' object has no attribute 'execute'

Segue o o código

```
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(host="reveka", user="carga", passwd="carga", db="dw")

if connection:
    print ("Conectado!\n")

#Realizando select para testar conexão 
mysql = '''\
    SELECT * FROM ft_venda
'''
cursor = connection.execute(mysql)

for Tabela in cursor:
    print(Tabela)
```

Comment: Não faltou o `cursor = connection.cursor()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Exemplo utilizando o seu código

Você pode fazer desta forma, como descrito na [documentação](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html)

```
import pymysql.cursors

connection = pymysql.connect(host='reveka',
                             user='carga',
                             password='carga',
                             db='dw')

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "SELECT * FROM ft_venda"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

## Alterações importantes

Como o [Rafael Barros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/139386/rafael-barros) citou, você precisa do [cursor](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html) para esta tarefa

```
import pymysql.cursors
```

E para pegar todos os registro utilizei [fetchall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940670/pymysql-fetchall-results-as-dictionary/35074393#35074393)

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

> Já que o exemplo da documentação só é retornado um registro

Comment: Obrigado Wictor Ajudou muito aqui :)

Answer (score 2):

Para começar, você adicionou a biblioteca `pymysql`, mas está querendo utilizar o `pymysql.cursor`. Faça o import correto:

```
import pymysql.cursor
```

Antes de chamar `cursor.execute()` você tem que definir que vai trabalhar com a variável `cursor`como `connection.cursor()`. Assim:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host="reveka", user="carga", passwd="carga", db="dw")


try:    
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        mysql = 'SELECT * FROM ft_venda'
        cursor.execute(mysql)
        resultado = cursor.fetchall()
        print(resultado)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Dica: na [documentação da biblioteca](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html) tem um exemplo de como fazer a chamada adequadamente e que pode até te dar uma ideia de como melhorar seu código caso você queira fazer tratamento da resposta no caso de erro com a conexão.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Rafael :)